# Google Closure decompiler?

Tags: decompiling, google-closure-compiler, google-closure, decompiler

I was looking for a way to decompile JavaScript that was compiled by Google Closure. I did find a Decompiler class (https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/source/browse/lib/rhino/src/org/mozilla/javascript/Decompiler.java?name=v20140407), however I haven't had much luck with it.

Anyone try this before or know of some other method?

Comment: I assume you're trying to reverse-engineer code that has been compiled in Advanced mode.  This will prove extremely difficult as the rewrites and optimizations can be very extensive.  Obfuscation is one of the major benefits of using Advanced mode, so you're probably out of luck here.  By using Advanced mode, the author of the source gets the benefit of obfuscation -- which means preventing you (the reader) from reverse-engineering it.

Answer (score 5):

Usually, I just run the code through the Closure Compiler in WHITESPACE mode and enable the pretty printing options.

Comment: Yea that might work when compiling the source but will that do anything for me if it's already compiled?

Comment: I suggest you try it.  What are you looking for other than just pretty formatted output?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to decompile the JS code. So, imagine  I minimized/compressed/compiled a JS file using Closure. Now I'd like to take that file and undo what CLosure did to it. That's what I'm looking to do.

Comment: The process is lossy so you can't get the original file back from the result: comments are removed, dead code eliminated, variables are renamed, constants are folded.  The best you can do is make the code look more readable thus the pretty printing suggestion.  If you originally compiled the code, you can save the source maps or the renaming maps and produce something closer to the original but then could just as easily have saved the original file.